# Redirection After authentication on shared host in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am also trying to deploy a ZendSkeletonApplication on a shared host but I am facing some problem regarding redirection. The problem is when a user try to login it gets stuck to /projectname/user/authenticate. It doesn't get redirected to dashboard after authentication.Unfortunately all i see is a white, empty page. Locally it worked perfectly Here it looks like Zend doesn't recognize that it should do anything with this url and redirecto to appropriate action.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See your servers error logs. White page is an indicator for a suppressed exception

Comment: Check that Sam told you or you can also put **ini_set("display_errors",true);** on your index.php and then edit your post and let us know about errors

Comment: @Sam There are no errors in the error logs

Comment: It works with a simple **phpinfo();** ? How have you connected your libraries/modules (using composer.phar ? manually ?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is presented by the new release of PHP. Try updating your version of php above 3.xx. **I upgraded to the latest version of php in the hosting and the problem was solved. PHP 5**